# Match each element of one array with elements of other array without loops

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

I want to match each element of one array (lessnum) with elements of the other array say (cc). Then multiply with a number from the third array (gl). I am doing using loops. The length of arrays are very large therefore it takes couple of hours. Is it possible to do without loops or make it faster. Here is the code, I am doing,

```
uniquec=sort(unique(cc));
maxc=max(uniquec);
c35p=0.35*maxc;
lessnum=uniquec(uniquec<=c35p);
greaternum=uniquec(uniquec>c35p);
gl=linspace(1,2,length(lessnum));
gr=linspace(2,1,length(greaternum));
 newC=zeros(size(cc));
for i=1:length(gl)
    newC(cc==lessnum(i))= cc(cc==lessnum(i)).*gl(i);
end
for i=1:length(gr)
    newC(cc==greaternum(i))= cc(cc==greaternum(i)).*gr(i);
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is instead of storing the values that are less than or greater than `c35p` in `lessnum` and `greaternum`, respectively, you should store the indices of these numbers. That way, you can directly access the `newC` variable using these indices and then multiply your linearly generated values.

Further modifications are explained in the code itself. If you have any confusion you can read the help for `unique`

Here is the modified code (I assume that `cc` is a one-dimensional array)

```
%randomly generate a cc vector
cc = randi(100, 1, 10);
% modified code below
[uniquec, ~, induniquec]=unique(cc, 'sorted'); % modified to explicitly specify the inbuilt sorting capability of unique and generate the indicies of unique values in the array
maxc=max(uniquec);
c35p=0.35*maxc;
lessnum=uniquec<=c35p; % instead of lessnum=uniquec(uniquec<=c35p);
greaternum=uniquec>c35p; % instead of greaternum=uniquec(uniquec>c35p);
gl=linspace(1,2,sum(lessnum));
gr=linspace(2,1,sum(greaternum));
% now there is no need for 'for' loops. We first modify the unique values as specified and then regenerate the required matrix using the indices obtained previously
newC=uniquec;
newC(lessnum) = newC(lessnum) .* gl;
newC(greaternum) = newC(greaternum) .* gr;
newC = newC(induniquec);
```

This new code will run much faster than the original one but is much more memory intensive depending on the number of unique values in your original array.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @EliahuAaron. My code didn't handle the duplicate values correctly. Will correct it.

Comment: Yes, way much faster, great technique, `newC = newC(induniquec);` avoids multiplications with `gl` and `gr` for duplicate values. It does consume more memory.

Comment: @ammportal If I execute one by one statement and if execute    
 `newC(greaternum) = newC(greaternum) .* gr;` before     `newC(lessnum) = newC(lessnum) .* gl;`
I get an other error. 
Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements.

Comment: Hello, your answer is great. But in my case the length of the array is 10342656. Matlab gives me out of memory error at `newC(lessnum) = newC(lessnum) .* gl;` . Out of memory. Type "help memory" for your options. Although, I have 64GB RAM.

Comment: @ammportal I got the answer. I just made gr and gl column vectors instead of row vectors because all other are column vectors.  Thank you for your great answer.

Comment: @EliahuAaron Yeah. Definitely takes up more memory but I guess it is fine for the OP's purposes.

Comment: @Kanjoo Happy to help you. Just make sure that everything works as expected in your code. Maybe compare the values obtained oorm your previous code and this one.